# Not getting the value in django template

Tags: django

models.py

```
class Stock(models.Model):
  name = models.CharField(verbose_name='Name of Stock', max_length=300)
  purchase_price = models.DecimalField(verbose_name='Purchase Price', blank=True, null=True, max_digits=30, decimal_places=2)
  pre_price = models.DecimalField(verbose_name='Last Day Price', blank=True, null=True, max_digits=30, decimal_places=2)
  current_price = models.DecimalField(verbose_name='Current Price', blank=True, null=True, max_digits=30, decimal_places=2)

def __str__(self):
    return self.name

class StockList(models.Model):
  user = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL)
  stock = models.ForeignKey(Stock)
  quantity = models.IntegerField(verbose_name='No.of Shares',default=0)
  timestamp = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True, auto_now_add=False)

  def __str__(self):
      return str(self.stock)

def market_value_reciever(sender, instance, *args, **kwargs):
  purchase_price = instance.stock.purchase_price
  quantity = instance.quantity
  market_value = purchase_price * quantity
  instance.market_value = market_value
  print(purchase_price)
  print(market_value)

pre_save.connect(market_value_reciever, sender=StockList)
```

html template

```
        {% for item in queryset %}
        <tr>
            <td>
              <a href="#">{{ item.stock.name }}</a>
            </td>
             <td>
              {{ item.purchase_price }}
            </td>
             <td>
              {{ item.quantity }}
            </td>
            <td>
              {{ item.market_value }}
            </td>


        </tr>
   {% endfor %}
```

Here I am getting only the value of quantity on html template, purchase price and market value fields are not getting on templates but its values are getting on terminal. Anybody can help, Thank you so much.

Comment: What view is rendering this template? What does your `Stock` model look like?

Comment: What's the point of that pre_save signal? What are you expecting to happen to that market_value attribute?

Comment: Create view rendering the template. Stock model is added. I just want to get the price and quantity multplied

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use the [@property](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#property) decorator in StockList model, so the template can render it:

```
class StockList(models.Model):

    @property
    def purchase_price(self):
        return self.stock.purchase_price

    @property
    def market_value(self):
        return self.purchase_price * self.quantity
```